# reltuples set to 0 after Postgres 12 upgrade

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I did an upgrade from Postgres 11.6 to 12.2 on AWS-RDS. Post upgrade seeing a couple of issues:

1. Seems like all reltuples were set to 0 post upgrade
2. Describe of an object results in error:
   ERROR:  column c.relhasoids does not exist
   LINE 1: ...riggers, c.relrowsecurity, c.relforcerowsecurity, c.relhasoi...

Comment: Seems like upgrading the client to Postgres 12 fixes #2. Still need an answer on why the upgrade is setting reltuples to 0

Comment: Did you run the `analyze` after the upgrade? (pg_upgrade will generate a `analyze_new_cluster` script for that). Which "describe" are you talking about? Given the error message, I would suspect you are using an outdated client that's not compatible with Postgres 12

Comment: Looks like older clients don't work for the \d command. I saw that somewhere else as well

Answer (score 1):

It is well known and well documented that stats are not carried over and so you need analyze your database after pg_upgrade.